# Set Dynamic Base Url in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to set dynamic base url in codeigniter due to few following reasons.

- localhost for development and reset when it goes live
- single application accessible from multiple domains
- ip address may change due to dhcp (locally)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

CodeIgniter will figure out the `base_url` by itself, so you can just do:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Comment: Hey, I had it set to *'';* but it cant locate my *assets* folder at all. And when I click on INSPECT it shows some different IP, I don't understand because the IP of my server is totally different. Im using codeigniter 3. I can't event ping the displayed IP.

Comment: It is not good answer. base_url() will return server host_name not actual domain you're using. I give a down vote for this.

Comment: @TerryLin this answer was posted 3 years ago, when CodeIgniter was at version 2.x. Your down vote is therefor somewhat ridiculous, but whatever.

Answer (score 22):

I just need to share my knowledge, since I already found the [answer](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Dynamic-Base-Url) as mention below.

Just overwrite the line in config/config.php with the following:

```
$config['base_url']    = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

If you are using the sub folder you can use following code:

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

Comment: There should also be some mechanism to auto detect the protocol i.e [ http / https ]    this should do the trick `$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === 0 ? 'https://' : 'http://'; `

Answer (score 11):

Just like say in the docs:

In case you need to allow e.g. multiple domains, or both http:// and https:// prefixes to be dynamically used depending on the request, remember that application/config/config.php is still a PHP script, in which you can create this logic with a few lines of code. For example:

```
$allowed_domains = array('domain1.tld', 'domain2.tld');
$default_domain  = 'domain1.tld';

if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $allowed_domains, TRUE))
{
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
else
{
    $domain = $default_domain;
}

if (! empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
{
    $config['base_url'] = 'https://'.$domain;
}
else
{
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$domain;
}
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer.... Question is still relevant to later CI versions, and this solution will still work.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can try this.

```
$base_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$base_url .= "://". @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .=     str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;
```

Comment: This is the simplest way for dynamic base_url..

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Janith's answer but I have a better and easier solution.

Set the config item in any config files (for example, I use it in routes.php), it will reset base_url before using in Controller.

```
$lang_code = 'en';
$root_domain = 'test.org';
$base_domain_url = 'http://' . $lang_code . '.' . $root_domain;

$this->config->set_item('base_url', $base_domain_url);
```

**Test it in Controller:**

```
echo base_url();
```

**Result:**

```
http://en.test.org
```

Comment: It works! But unfortunately just at Controller that I am.

Example: If I was at LoginController and I set `$this->config->set_item('base_url', $base_domain_url);` it will work. But, if I was at another Controller, and call to `$this->config->item('base_url')`  it will load the previous base_url located at config.php

Answer (score 2):

```
***This code below is used for production:***
        
$base_url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
        
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use...

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = $root;
```

Comment: why wrapping `$root` in double quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for command line, localhost and production.

```
$protocol = is_https() ? "https://" : "http://";
$host = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : "";
if(is_cli())
{
    $config['base_url'] = '';
}
elseif(stristr($host, "localhost") !== FALSE || (stristr($host, '192.168.') !== FALSE) || (stristr($host, '127.0.0') !== FALSE))
{
    $config['base_url'] = $protocol.$host."/PROJECT_FOLDER/";
}
else
{
    $allowed_hosts = ['sajansaj.com', 'www.sajansaj.com'];
    $config['base_url'] = in_array($host, $allowed_hosts) ? $protocol.$host."/" : "we-do-not-recognise-this-host.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was presenting the error of [mixed content](http://in%20my%20case%20I%20was%20presenting%20the%20error%20of%20mixed%20content,%20for%20https%20using%20proxy,%20I%20used%20https%20and%20everything%20worked%20out.) for https using proxy, I used https and everything worked out.
Just overwrite the line in config/config.php with the following:

```
$config['base_url']    = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```