# How to set Dynamic base url to https in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try the use a dynamic base url in this post:

[Set Dynamic Base Url in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075257/set-dynamic-base-url-in-codeigniter)

But I used to be use the http, but now, I would like to change to https, how can I do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In your config/config.php, try this:

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

Comment: I used your code it works fine but when I print `base_url()` inside js it always return http, I don't understand why?

Answer (score 2):

```php
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

this works for me with virtualhost setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**codeigniter hooks**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/hooks.html) in pre_controller you just change the base_url http to https by string replace and set the base url

Answer (score 0):

simply use this $config['base_url'] = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);