# Codeigniter Subdomain folder added to end of Url

Tags: php, asp.net, codeigniter

If my root website www folder is /

and the subdomain folder is /subdomain

I can either get to the the address using one of the following

- http://subdomain.website.com/
- http://www.website.com/subdomain

Now if I access the site using the http://subdomain.website.com, The codeigniter treats the base_url() as http://subdomain.website.com/subdomain is there away of stripping the subdomin from the end if the subdomain segment has the same name?

I could strip it on a case by case basis, but I'm hoping there is a way to do this using one of the system configuration files.

Comment: You're looking for mod_rewrite rules (possibly in .htaccess); the framework is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are asking, has something to do with setting up dynamic base url in codeigniter. They have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075257/set-dynamic-base-url-in-codeigniter) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415025/how-to-set-dynamic-base-url-to-https-in-codeigniter). 
Hope you find it helpfull.