# Hide first url segment, Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, hide

I'm using one Codeigniter installation with multiple directories and each directory has it's own config.php in wich the "base_url" it's defined.

Example:

```
/server/codeigniter_files/
/server/htdocs/directory1/
/server/htdocs/directory2/
```

etc..

So the HTTP looks like this: www.abc.com/directory1, www.abc.com/directory2 etc..

Can I hide the "directoryX" segment from the URL keepin in mind that the config.php file must have the base_url containing "directoryX"?

I'm using lighttpd on a Debian server.

Comment: If i understand your question i think you can, just define what you want in application/config/routes. And the names that you use in the URL do not have to match the controller names or method. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: That wouldn't work because the routing will have effect only on segments after the base_url.

    example.com/class/function/id/ where example.com is the base_url.

In my case it is

     example.com/directory1/class/function/id/

Comment: hmmmm check these answers out, might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075257/set-dynamic-base-url-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download CodeIgniter files under "server" directory. Rename your "Application" folder to "directory1". then make another copy of your "directory1" folder and rename it to directory2. Now Create a new folder under "server" forder and name it Application and move your "directory1" and "directory2" into "Application" folder.

Move your index.php file to "htdocs" folder. Open index.php file in your favourite editor and edit following lines.

$system_path = 'system';

to

$system_path = '../system';

And

$application_folder = 'application';

to

$application_folder = '../application/directory1';

and save it as directory1.php under htdocs folder

Now make an other copy of your index file and save it as directory2.php

open your directory2.php file and change the following lines

$system_path = 'system';

to

$system_path = '../system';

And

$application_folder = 'application';

to

$application_folder = '../application/directory2';

you can access your directory1 site with following url

localhost/directory1.php

localhost/directory2.php

you can change directory1.php and directory2.php files name to whatever you want and use .htaccess to hide directory1.php and directory2.php from url.

for more information, you can visit following page
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html

Comment: Above solution is for multiple applications running on same codeigniter installation with individual config files for each application. but if you are working on one application and want to organize your application with sub-folders, then you can create sub-folders in "controllers" folder as follow Application/controllers/directory1 and use routing option to hide/route directory1/directory2.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution and it's working (localhost/directory1.php) but not sure how to edit the lighttpd.conf to actually hide the directory1.php.